# SQLITE - Updating a single row for each unique column pair

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite

I have really basic knowledge in SQL and this seems like a task that requires a complex query to avoid doing multiple queries in a program loop.

I have a table such as the following with 'filename' as UNIQUE column:

```
title   subtitle    filename    comment     selected

abc     123         f1.txt      abc         0
xyz     999         f2.txt      bla         0
abc     123         f3.txt      ppp         0
poc     232         f4.txt      ppp         0
xyz     220         f5.txt      ppp         0
xyz     999         f6.txt      ppp         0
```

I need to update the 'selected' column to 1 for only a single row (doesn't matter which) for each unique (title, subtitle) pair. This is how the table should be after the query is processed:

```
abc     123         f1.txt      abc         1
xyz     999         f2.txt      bla         1
abc     123         f3.txt      ppp         0
poc     232         f4.txt      ppp         1
xyz     220         f5.txt      ppp         1
xyz     999         f6.txt      ppp         0
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the IDs of those unique rows:

```
SELECT MIN(rowid)  -- or whatever your primary key is
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY title, subtitle
```

(It does not matter whether you use MIN or MAX.)

Then update those rows:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET selected = 1
WHERE rowid IN (SELECT MIN(rowid)
                FROM MyTable
                GROUP BY title, subtitle)
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, I think you can do this:

```
update table
    set selected = 1
    where not exists (select 1
                      from table t2
                      where t2.name < t.name or (t2.name = t.name and t2.title < t.title)
                     );
```